# Cambiar propiedades con un range slider

Tags: javascript, html, slider

Hola me gustaría saber como puedo cambiar el tamaño de un div de forma gradual con un range slider.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido Anomino para que sea bien recibida tu pregunta por la comunidad editala y haz un [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

```js
var range = document.getElementById("my-range");
var square = document.getElementById("square");

range.addEventListener("change", function() {
  square.style.zoom = this.value;
});
```

```css
#square {
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input id="my-range" type="range" step="0.25" min="0.25" max="4" />

<div id="square"></div>
```

[creditos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919424/how-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-using-form-type-range-using-jquery)